# Save active Scene Unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, save, scene

I am trying to save modification made when the scene is loaded (new object instantiated ..) and I would like to load them after.
My script is :

```
public void SaveGame()
{    
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Level", SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
    PlayerPrefs.Save();
    print("Game saved!");
    Debug.Log("Game normally saved " + scene.name);
}
public void LoadGame()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Level"));
    print("Game loaded!");
    Debug.Log("Game normally Loaded ");
}
```

The problem is when I save the game , it saves the Scene which is in my asset but I want to save this scene without any modifications.
I think that I should get the scene active but with modifications so I should modify this part of code:

```
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Level", SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
```

So is there any way to do this ?

Comment: You are not saving the changes made in the scene, you are just saving the Index of the scene.

Comment: For saving the modification you will need to store in somehow the GameObject using XML/JSON and then load it from the data stored.

Comment: aa ok i see thnx a lot